# wp8:Handle Toast notification when application is in backgroung

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

While my app is running I can receive toast notification,on ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e) event handler as keys in e.Collection.

If my app is not running and a toast notification arrives, a toast is displayed but how i can i handle this notification?

I mean which event is fire when my application is not running and notification arrives.

I know background agent but its not fulfill my requirement

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone platform is responsible to handle `Push Notifications` and developers don't have a direct access for notification handling when an app is not running. That means you can't do any background logic after `Toast` is received. But when `Toast` message contains `<wp:Param>` value with an `Uri` to a specific app page then user will be redirected to this page, if user taps a `Toast` popup. So, you can do specific job after user tapped a `Toast` popup. To accomplish it, you need add an parameter to `Uri`, for example `/YourPage?IsToast=true` and override `OnNavigatedTo` method of the page to run your business logic:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("IsToast"))
            {
                //do your business here
            }
    }
```

For other cases you need to use a background worker.

Comment: :thanks for replay but i just want to call my web service when notification is come.when my application is running and notification come than i got the event ShellToastNotificationReceived so i can call my web service but when application is backgroung and notification come.now when i start my application than how i know how many notification come?

Comment: There is no way. Actually it seems `Push Notifications` are not suitable for your purpose. I would suggest you to use `BackroundWorker` or even to call the web-service after the app is launched to check about the changes on the server.

Answer (score 1):

yes we can handle the toast notification. once the user clicks on toast notification we can send a request to our web service and do our job.

what happens when an user clicks on toast notification is it will redirect to the application launching event in App.Xaml.cs page. in that event depending upon the toast content you can proceed to the next step.

hope this helps.

still if you didn't get it done, just drop a mail to me

happy coding.