# Is there way to handle Tile Notification Recieved in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, tile, mpns

Now we can handle Raw and Toast notification revcieved event via:

```
        _httpChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(httpChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);
        _httpChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(httpChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);ere
```

But there is no event for Tile recieved. How to handle the Tile Recieved?

Thanks!

Comment: The purpose for Tile notifications is to update an app tile. Why do you need to handle a Tile notification? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317959/wp8handle-toast-notification-when-application-is-in-backgroung/17319031#17319031

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle or be informed of a tile notification being received.

Comment: Agree. As a workaround, I ever considered to use send Raw Notification instead, and then update the Tile in event handler HttpNotificationReceived; but device can only recieve Raw Notification when app is in foreground, give up.